# base64 file to be downloaded in capacitor iOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, angular, capacitor

I've an app made in angular and I'm packaging the app with capacitor for both iOS and Android.
The app contains attachments which I request from back end and the result is base64 string. I manage to download the file without issues in Web, but the files are not downloadable in mobile version.
Here's the download code.

```
<div *ngFor="let attachment of attachmentsInput, let i = index">
                                <div class="row pl-1 pr-1">
                                    <div class="col-lg-7">
                                        <a role="button" (click)="downloadFile(i)" class="hover">
                                            
                                            <span class="hover">{​​​​​{​​​​​attachment.name}​​​​​}​​​​​</span>
                                        </a>
                                        <a style="display: none;" id="downloadLinkId+{​​​​​{​​​​​i}​​​​​}​​​​​" [href]="attachmentsInput[i].toBeDownloaded" [download]="attachmentsInput[i].name"></a>
                                    </div>
                                 
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Download file code:

```
async downloadFile(index) {​​​​​​
  this.attachmentsInput[index].toBeDownloaded = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('data:image/jpg;base64,' + this.attachmentsInput[index].content);


if (this.attachmentsInput[index].toBeDownloaded)
      document.getElementById('downloadLinkId+' + index).click();
}
```

Is there a problem in using document.getElementById ?

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: I'm getting this error: "Failed to open URL data:image/jpg;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABzEAAANWCAYAAAB+vnHgAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADs ... rkJggg==: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-10814 "(null)" UserInfo={_LSLine=229, _LSFunction=-[_LSDOpenClient openURL:options:completionHandler:]}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

downloading from the link does not work in native applications. For such, you need to use the [Filesystem API](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/filesystem),
for example:

```
import { FilesystemDirectory, Plugins } from '@capacitor/core';
const { Filesystem } = Plugins;

await Filesystem.writeFile({
    path: "filename.txt",
    data: "base64 data",
    directory: FilesystemDirectory.ExternalStorage,
  });
```